# Ada vector of enumerated type

Tags: comparison, containers, enumeration, ada

I am trying to created a vector of an enumerated type in Ada, but the compiler seems to expect an equality function overload.  How do I telll the compiler to just use the default equal function.  Here's what I have:

```ada
package HoursWorkedVector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Natural,DAY_OF_WEEK);
--where Day of week is defined as an enumeration
```

When I try to compile, I get the message:

```
no visible subprogram matches the specification for "="
```

Do I need to create a comparison function to have a vector of an enumerated type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is DAY_OF_WEEK defined in the same package as HoursWorkedVector?  Also, is DAY_OF_WEEK a renaming declaration?

Comment: "Renaming declaration" in my previous comment was a mistake.  I should have asked, is DAY_OF_WEEK a subtype declaration?

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes the error?  Right now, I think we're missing too much information.

Comment: It appears that you did not need the rest of the code, as your first question lead me straight to the solution.  In fact, DAY_OF_WEEK is indeed defined in a different package.  I just didn't include the name here, because I thought it would be irrelevant, but when I added the "use" clause, the file compiled without a hitch, so, since I hate using "use" clauses, is there a way to create my vector type without having a "use package" clause?

Comment: `package HoursWorkedVector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Natural, My_Other_Package.DAY_OF_WEEK, My_Other_Package."=");`

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you, and ajb very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html) starts like this:

```
generic
   type Index_Type is range <>;
   type Element_Type is private;
   with function "=" (Left, Right : Element_Type)
      return Boolean is <>;
package Ada.Containers.Vectors is
```

The meaning of `<>` in a generic formal function is defined by [RM 12.6(10)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-6.html):

> If a generic unit has a subprogram_default specified by a box, and the
>   corresponding actual parameter is omitted, then it is equivalent to an
>   explicit actual parameter that is a usage name identical to the
>   defining name of the formal.

So if, as you said in the comments, `DAY_OF_WEEK` is defined in another package, your instantiation is equivalent to

```
package HoursWorkedVector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Natural, Other_Package.DAY_OF_WEEK, "=");
```

which doesn't work because the `"="` that compares `DAY_OF_WEEK` values is not visible.

You can include `Other_Package."="` in the instantiation, as suggested in a comment.  There are at least three ways to make `"="` visible, so that your original instantiation would work:

1. `use Other_Package;`  This will make `"="` directly visible, but it will also make everything else defined in that package directly visible.  This may not be what you want.
2. `use type Other_Package.DAY_OF_WEEK;`  This makes all the operators of `DAY_OF_WEEK` directly visible, including `"<"`, `"<="`, etc., as well as all the enumeration literals, and any other primitive subprograms of `DAY_OF_WEEK` that you may have declared in `Other_Package`.  This is probably the favorite solution, unless for some reason it would be a problem to make the enumeration literals visible.
3. Use a renaming declaration to redefine `"="`:

   `function "=" (Left, Right : DAY_OF_WEEK) return Boolean
       renames Other_Package."=";`

   This makes `"="` directly visible.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically selects the predefined equality operator:

```ada
with
  Ada.Containers.Vectors;

package Solution is
   type Day_Of_Week is (Work_Day, Holiday);

   package Hours_Worked_Vector is
     new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type   => Natural,
                                 Element_Type => Day_Of_Week);
end Solution;
```